# Time it will take to crack a password file?

Tags: combinations

I'm trying to answer a multiple-choice question which is the following:

Consider the security of a password file, which includes a 10 bit salt and all passwords are hashed, but known to consist of exactly 8 characters from the following alphabet:

```
    lowercase letters ('a' to 'z')
    uppercase letters ('A' to 'Z')
    digits ('0' to '9')
    the special characters (., -, _, +, <, >, =, @)
```

Assume that a password cracking system, which is able to check 12 billion (10^12) guesses per second and is able to run around the clock all year, is used to crack the password file. Which of the following worst case estimates for cracking the password file is most accurate?

The answer is **Two years.**

What I did is, I would say since the salts are fixed and there are 70 (26+26+10+8) characters for each bit and the password consists of 8bits-> 70^8 possible combinations. And this answer divided by 12,000,000,000 <strike>12*10^12</strike>, but this gives me 48040 seconds ? [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=70%5E8+%2F+12%2C000%2C000%2C000)

EDIT: corrected 12 billion

Comment: 12 Billion isn't equal to $12*10^{12}$

Comment: that would be 12 Trillion^

Comment: The correction of billion to $10^9$ gets you to $48040$ seconds, which is a little over $13$ hours, still far off $2$ years.  I believe salts are assumed known by the attacker, which justifies not using those bits in the calculation.

Comment: @RossMillikan what does salys mean?

Comment: It reads salts to me

Comment: Yes salts sorry, I made a typo here.

Comment: You listed that each password has a $10$ bit salt, but you ignored that in your calculation.  I was agreeing that was the correct approach because you are assumed to know the salt.

Comment: This formulation is somehow confusing. Assuming the encoding is ASCII. How can the salt be only 10 bits when 1 character in ASCII is 1 byte (8 bits). This means the salt is 1 and 2/10 characters long.